# Reading CSV file into a JTable created with Netbeans Swing GUI

Tags: java

I am trying to read lines of data, separated by commas [,] from a CSV file.
I have been able to read the data into a string array. array[0] lists everything that would be in the first column and so forth. I've created my application using Netbeans GUI and my current table is placed via drag and drop on to a JPanel. How can I create the JTable using my CSV file? I'm am not allowed to use a CSVReader (such as OpenCSV). Thank you.

Comment: Click [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) to learn how to use tables in Java.

Answer (score 0):

After reading the tutorial of table basic you would need to load the data into a `DefaultTableModel` and add the model to a `JTable`.

So the basic code would be:

```
DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(...);

while(...)
{
    fields = line.split("[,]");
    model.add( fields );
}

JTable table = new JTable( model );
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane( table );
frame.add( scrollPane );
```

Comment: Hello, is there a way to add a table model to a JTable that has been created from NetBeans GUI. A lot of the table code is uneditable due to it being generated automatically.